# Should I answer "off-topic" questions before casting a close-vote?

Tags: discussion, voting-to-close

This is regarding a question, which to me appears to be "off-topic" as it is a basic programming question; and also most probably might also be closed as most of the questions from the same user are.

What should I do when I encounter the question? Would it be good to answer the question and then cast a close vote? Because after the question is closed, users are not allowed to answer the questions; and if the question is not completely removed (just closed) from the site, it would remain unanswered and might not help any visitor if they accidentally come to the question to find a solution.

Comment: I have not provided a link to the question, because I felt by doing so the user might get offended; which are not by intentions.

Comment: By casting a close vote, the question may or may not get closed. So its better to answer if you have the time and correct answer or atleast guide him/her through comments.

Comment: @2-Stroker I was pretty much sure the question was about to be closed (it had 4 close votes already on it). And I agree to what kiamlaluno has to say, that if I am pretty much sure the question is off-topic, not answering it (and off course flagging it) should be the reaction. This would discourage the user from asking such questions again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you think the question is really off-topic, then vote to close it, and don't answer it. The reasons not to answer it are:

- You would give the user the habit of asking off-topic questions, since they get answers. Closing the questions, once they have an answer, would not be an incentive to avoid the OP asks off-topic questions, as the OP's purpose is getting an answer, not to keep the OP's questions open.
- It could be the question is on-topic, but the OP didn't express the question correctly, and made it appear off-topic. If then the question is made clearer, an answer that doesn't provide a Drupal solution would not make sense, and it should be deleted.

Comment: Yes, I think it makes sense not to answer the question at all; which might encourage more of the similar question. But, before asking this, I actually did answer one of the question, which was closed later. I'll keep in mind I won't do that again ;-)

Comment: It could be you don't think the question should be closed, and you answer it; that is fine.